# Cfar Algorithm Implementation

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-filters, algorithms, radar, adaptive-filters

I am trying to implementation Cfar algorithm to our radar signal processing algorithm. I obtained some output but I want to be sure that is right. Cfar algorithm's output below like, I'm interpreting these outputs like this, where it should just specify something at the detected distance and speed, there's just a gap in that range. is this true? if not how can i fix it? So detected object's range value is 4.88 meter and it's velocity value is 0.39 m/s.

this is range and velocity which is detected object

[image]

The outputs I get after applying the cfar algorithm.

I was confused that the object detected here came out as a space, frankly.
[image]

[image: enter image descriptionhgjhj here]

[![[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvDd4.png]
[image: enter image descriptioaaaaan here]

Comment: There's couple Cfar results at MathWorks File Exchange : https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange?q=Cfar I did not check these because of radar tehc is out of my knowledge.

Comment: Without code or a description of what kind of radar this is (FMCW, pulsed-Doppler, etc.) we can't help you further as this makes a big difference on how filtering is set up.